# document.getElementsByClassName() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to create a fallback in the absence of jQuery, as I have a div with the class 'container' and a style `display: none`

I use jquery to `fadeIn()` this div, to create a fade effect on page (re)load (I know there are better ways to do this, however I would like to do it this way.)

However, in case of lack of jQuery `(!window.jQuery)` I am creating a JavaScript solution to make my page visible.

But my attempts at using `document.getElementsByClassName()` have so far failed, and always return *'undefined'*
I understand I can loop through them, but this seems a little OTT for targeting *one* element.

None of the following attempts have worked:

1. All together, with [0] node selection:

   ```
   document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].style.display = "block";
   ```
2. All together, without [0], as I want to style all (1) of the
   elements with the class name "container":

`document.getElementsByClassName("container").style.display = "block";`

3. Set as a variable, then take the [0] node and style it*

   ```
   var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
   container[0].style.display = "block";
   ```

N.B. I know there are many questions of this nature on SO, however mine is different as there is only one element with the class am trying to select, so I would rather not loop through them.

The console throws the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined(anonymous function)

And also when I `console.log` them in each instance, it says they're `undefined`

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Yeah, it throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined(anonymous function)` @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: The first example you have (which is the correct method) works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/b48prmv4/

Comment: Can you post a broken fiddle?  As @RoryMcCrossan mentioned, this works fine.

Comment: Are you running it after the DOM is ready? May be you are running the code while the ".container" isn't present yet. Because the code document.getElementsByClassName("class")[index] is the correct one.

Comment: First of all, why create your own fallback for jQuery when there are already several lightweight alternatives to jQuery (http://tutorialzine.com/2012/04/5-lightweight-jquery-alternatives/)? Further, consider adding a JSFiddle with your code, which makes it easier to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Ah strange, the JSFiddle seems to be working @Tom

Comment: @joe_young : Are you running any other JS code before this code? Fatal errors block the execution of all other code.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and suggestions. the reason it wasn't working was because my code was being called before `.container` existed. I solved this by putting it in `window.onload=function() { ... } Again, thank y'all very much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most likely running that code before the elements of class `container` exist.

Your jQuery probably works because you have it in a `$(document).ready` callback (`$( function( ) { ...` is a common way to do this).

Either add your non jQuery code to a `window.onload` event handler, or simply move your script to lower in your HTML than the elements are that you want it to select. Right before the closing `</body>` is a common place for scripts that require the whole document to be available in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you, this was what was going wrong; I had recognised that $(document).ready(function() wasn't going to work without jQuery so had put it at the very start of the document. This meant that it was, indeed, called before `.container` existed. I solved this by putting it in `window.onload=function() { ... }. Again, thank you very much. Will accept when I can :)

Comment: @joe_young Your are welcome. Also note that if you bind to `window.onload` like that you will overwrite other functions that were bound the same way (and other scripts could inadvertently overwrite yours). It is better to use `window.addEventListener( 'onload', function ( ) { ...` or something like that.I forget the exact syntax and I'm on my phone so it's not that easy to lookup. Even though the addEventListener version is better I think it is not as cross browser friendly with IE up to 7 or something. There is another way to do it in IE and a way to detect which version to use as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your code in an `onload` function:

```
window.onload=function(){
    // Your JS code goes here
}
```

Alternatively, put your JS code at the very bottom of your HTML body.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Start of head section -->
        <!-- Your HTML head content goes here -->
        <!-- End of head section -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Start of body section -->
        <!-- Your HTML body content goes here -->
        <!-- End of body section -->
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            // Your JS code goes here
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelector(".container")` which will automatically select the first item in the node list for you.

Comment: I think you mean `querySelectorAll()`. While you're technically correct in that it's an alternative, there's no reason what the OP has shouldn't be working, so there must be another underlying problem.

Comment: Well I actually did mean queryselector(".container") since he is just interested in the first element. Its outlined here [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) 
But you're right, his code should be working.

Comment: You're right, sorry I meant to correct the capitalisation, not the method: `querySelector()`